# Find + -printf + sort conflict?

Tags: find, sort, printf

I need to pass a list of sorted, quoted FLAC file names to SoX for concatenation but am having trouble getting sort to work the way I expect it to.

If I use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.flac" | sort
```

I get exactly what I expect:

```
./01-Lordy.flac
./02-Both Sides Now.flac
./03-Solitary Man.flac
./04-Holly Holy.flac
./05-Cherry Cherry.flac
./06-Kentucky Woman.flac
./07-Sweet Caroline.flac
./08-Thank the Lord for the Nightime.flac
./09-And the Singer Sings His Song.flac
./10-Brother Loves Traveling Salvation Show.flac
```

However, I can't really use that for what I'm doing since I need a quoted list with no newlines. I know -printf can do that for me, but when I try:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.FlAc" -printf "\"%p\" " | sort
```

I wind up with a list of file names that are quoted and separated by a single space (good!) but they aren't sorted (bad!). Or at least they aren't sorted the way I expect them to be:

```
"./08-Thank the Lord for the Nightime.flac" "./03-Solitary Man.flac" "./09-And the Singer Sings His Song.flac" "./05-Cherry Cherry.flac" "./06-Kentucky Woman.flac" "./10-Brother Loves Traveling Salvation Show.flac" "./07-Sweet Caroline.flac" "./02-Both Sides Now.flac" "./01-Lordy.flac" "./04-Holly Holy.flac"
```

Maybe even weirder, if I just for the sake of testing use the same code but add a newline:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.FlAc" -printf "\"%p\" "\\n | sort
```

The sort works even if the output is back to not being what I need:

```
"./01-Lordy.flac" 
"./02-Both Sides Now.flac" 
"./03-Solitary Man.flac" 
"./04-Holly Holy.flac" 
"./05-Cherry Cherry.flac" 
"./06-Kentucky Woman.flac" 
"./07-Sweet Caroline.flac" 
"./08-Thank the Lord for the Nightime.flac" 
"./09-And the Singer Sings His Song.flac" 
"./10-Brother Loves Traveling Salvation Show.flac"
```

This is under Ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Do you have to use `find` here, for the recursion? Or are all the desired files in the same directory? (I ask, given the `-maxdepth 1` and the sample output indicating the same directory)

Comment: I think what you're overlooking is that `sort` sorts *lines* (or, with GNU `sort -z`, null-delimited elements) - it should be no surprise that it doesn't sort filenames when they're all on a *single* line

Comment: If you a) are using GNU sed and b) you really need to find your files recursively, you can use this: `find . -iname '*.flac' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 sox ...` instead of messing with quoting and unquoting.

Comment: @mosvy I was just experimenting with that idea; that seems like a good additional answer!

Comment: If you're trying to collect filenames to pass to SoX as command-line arguments, you do *not* want to put quotes around them. Quotes are parsed only when they're actually part of the command, not when they're in date (e.g. from a variable or command substitution). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quotes-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-variables) for an example.

Comment: If I don't quote the file names, SoX is tripped up by whitespace. Feeding it quoted file names works fine, but without proper sorting the results aren't what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the files are all in the same directory, and you want to pass a list of sorted filenames to `sox`, then the bash shell could do that directly:

```
shopt -s nocaseglob
sox *.flac
```

The `nocaseglob` shell option allows the wildcard to pick up foo.FLAC, foo.Flac, foo.flaC, etc. The wildcard expands to an alphabetically sorted list, much like a bare `sort` would. It would, for example, put `9-file.flac` after any filename that started with `8`.

Thanks to @mosvy for a simplification of the above bash-ism into a wildcard that should work with any shell:

```
sox *.[Ff][Ll][Aa][Cc]
```

The brackets allow any combination of upper- and lower-case letters in the "flac" extension, in order to match what your `find ... -iname "*.FlAc"` was doing.

Comment: no need for `nocaseglob`; `sox *.[fF][lL][aA][cC]` will do just fine, in any shell.

Comment: Thank you everyone. `sox *.[fF][lL][aA][cC]` looks like it works while `printf '%s\n' *.[Ff][Ll][Aa][Cc]` looks like it gives me what I need to double-check that the order is correct.